# Why R "dplyr" package not loaded on web by shiny-server?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I have installed web R Studio and shiny-server on AWS instance.
The app is running fine from web studio but failed on www:3838 with error:
"Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in library.dynam (lib, package, package.lib): shared object ‘dplyr.so’ not found". I get the error from shiny server log file.

If we run "Hello" R shiny app

```
 library(shiny) - this works
 library(dplyr) - with this web not works
```

Comment: Did you actually install the `dplyr` package on your web server instance? Something like `install.packages("dplyr")`? Are you sure the package was installed successfully? Maybe try reinstalling?

Comment: Yes. I installed it and it works when running "app.R" via web r studio. I guess it's something with permissions for shiny-server

Comment: What use are you running as when you use RStudio (or when you installed the package)? What user runs the web application?

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue for shiny-server to download the package. Can you confirm that where you have the shiny-server hosted can connect to the internet?

Comment: Check your config file in `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` and see if the `run_as` parameter is set to root. If it is, you might want to change it to the name of your login user (assuming you are not logging in as root)

Comment: shiny-server usually runs as `shiny user`. Every libraries installed by your user, will be not available. You can either install libraries system wide (not recomended), run the server as yourself (check `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`), or change permission to your local library, so that the shiny user can read it.